# Loop optimization. How does register renaming break dependencies? What is execution port capacity?

Tags: performance, optimization, x86, cpu-architecture, micro-optimization

I am analyzing an example of a loop from Agner Fog's optimization_assembly. I mean the 12.9 chapter.
The code is: ( I simplified a bit)

```
L1: 
    vmulpd ymm1, ymm2, [rsi+rax] 
    vaddpd ymm1, ymm1, [rdi+rax] 
    vmovupd [rdi+rax], ymm1
    add rax, 32  
    jl L1
```

And I have some questions:

1. The author said that there is no loop-carried dependency. I don't understand why it is so. ( I skipped the case of `add rax, 32` ( it is loop-carried indeed, but only one cycle)).  But, after all, the next iteration cannot modify `ymm1` register before the previous iteration will not have finished. Maybe register-renaming plays a role here?
2. Let's assume that there is a loop-carried dependency.
   `vaddpd ymm1, ymm1, [rdi+rax] -> vmovupd [rdi+rax], ymm1`

And let latency for first is 3, and latency for second is 7.

( In fact, there is no such dependency, but I would like to ask a hypothetical question)

Now, How to determine a total latency. Should I add latencies and the result would be 10? I have no idea.

3. It is written:

> There are two 256-bit read operations, each using a read port for two
>   consecutive clock cycles, which is indicated as 1+ in the table. Using
>   both read ports (port 2 and 3), we will have a throughput of two
>   256-bit reads in two clock cycles. One of the read ports will make an
>   address calculation for the write in the second clock cycle. The write
>   port (port 4) is occupied for two clock cycles by the 256-bit write.
>   The limiting factor will be the read and write operations, using the
>   two read ports and the write port at their maximum **capacity**.

What exactly is **capacity** for ports? How can I determine them, for example for IvyBridge (my CPU).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, the whole point of register renaming is to break dependency chains when an instruction writes a register without depending on the old value.  The destination of a `mov`, or the write-only destination operand of AVX instructions, is like this.  Also zeroing idioms like [`xor eax,eax` are recognized as independent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and) of the old value, even though they *appear* to have the old value as an input.

   **See also [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113527/why-does-mulss-take-only-3-cycles-on-haswell-different-from-agners-instruction/45114487#45114487) for a more detailed description of register-renaming,** and some performance experiments with multiple loop-carried dependency chains in flight at once.
2. Without renaming, `vmulpd` couldn't write `ymm1` until `vmovupd` had read its operand ([Write-After-Read hazard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_(computer_architecture)#Data_hazards)), but it wouldn't have to wait for `vmovupd` to *complete*.  See a computer architecture textbook to learn about in-order pipelines and stuff.  I'm not sure if any out-of-order CPUs without [register renaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_renaming) exist.

   update: [early OoO CPUs used scoreboarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoreboarding) to do some limited out-of-order execution without register renaming, but were much more limited in their capacity to find and exploit instruction-level parallelism.
3. Each of the two load ports on IvB has a capacity of one 128b load per clock.  And also of one address-generation per clock.

   In theory, SnB/IvB can sustain a throughput of 2x 128b load and 1x 128b store per clock, but only by using 256b instructions.  They can only generate two addresses per clock, but a 256b load or store only needs one address calculation per 2 cycles of data transfer.  See [Agner Fog's microarch guide](https://agner.org/optimize/)

   Haswell added a dedicated store AGU on port 7 that handles simple addressing modes only, and widened the data paths to 256b.  A single cycle can do a peak of 96 bytes total loaded + stored. (But some unknown bottleneck limits sustained throughput to less than that.  On Skylake-client, about 84 bytes / cycle reported by Intel, and matches my testing.)

   (IceLake client reportedly can sustain 2x64B loaded + 1x64B stored per cycle, or 2x32B stored, according to a recent update to Intel's optimization guide.)

---

Also note that your [indexed addressing modes won't micro-fuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046634/micro-fusion-and-addressing-modes/31027695#31027695), so fused-domain uop throughput is also a concern.

Comment: Before Tomasulo's there was scoreboarding, but it's kind of bad for obvious reasons

Comment: You can get to ~96 bytes per cycle, IIRC. If a store address is eligible, I think it will almost always go to p7, at least if there is any other pressure on p23.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Yeah, that was a wrong guess at the mechanism.  But something does limit sustained throughput.  I tested just now on i7-6700k with a loop that loads with `vmovups ymm0, [rdi]` ; `vmovups ymm1, [rdi+32]`, and does an independent store `vmovups [rdi+64], ymm2`.  (and dec/jnz).  It runs 1152M cycles for 1000M iterations, with uops evenly distributed between ports 2, 3, and 7.  `rdi` is 4k aligned in the BSS.  `96 * 1000/1151` ~= 83.4, matching Intel's reported ~84 byte/cycle Skylake sustained throughput.